# Родительный или винительный падеж?

Tags: склонение, падежи, множественное-число, родительный-или-винительный

Совсем запуталась. В предложении "...но поводов паниковать он дает предостаточно" слово *поводов* в каком падеже? Родительном или винительном? Мне почему-то кажется, что в винительном, но окончание не совпадает.

Заранее спасибо за  ответы.

Comment: Это родительный падеж. И окончание совпадает с родительным. )

Answer (score 3):

**Родительный** - предостаточно *чего?* поводов. Формы **родительного падежа** требует наречие **предостаточно**, ср.: *много книг, мало времени, достаточно слов*, *предостаточно поводов*. А словосочетание "предостаточно поводов" в целом зависит от глагола **даёт** и отвечает в целом на вопрос винительного падежа.

Answer (score 1):

Он дает  предостаточно (=много) поводов паниковать.

Здесь оценочное наречие является аналогом неопределенно-количественного числительного "много" и образует количественно-именное сочетание "предостаточно (чего? Р.п.) поводов". **В таких сочетаниях числительное управляет Р.п существительного**.

**Но все сочетание в данном случае употреблено в форме В.п.:** Он дает  (что? В.п.) предостаточно (=много) поводов паниковать.